# Hyperref with tcolorbox in theorems with or without proof

Tags: hyperref, tcolorbox

I wrote a document with theorems and proofs. The proofs are saved in other files and appear at the end of the document (with `\tcbsartrecording`). I also have a `\tcbset{no demo/.style={no recording,after upper=}}` when there is no proof and it works fine.
What I would like, now, is links between theorems and proofs. And I don't know how to do it.
Here is a MWE (a little long, sorry):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{book}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket},math-style=french]{unicode-math}
\usepackage[scale={0.75,0.8},footskip=1.5cm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{prop}{Proposition}{% Proposition
    enhanced,breakable,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,separator sign dash,
    lowerbox=ignored,
    sharp corners,
    hypertarget=prop@#1,hyperlink=demop@#1,
    label={prop@\thetcbcounter},
    savelowerto=demo-\thetcbcounter.tex,
    record={\string\demop{\thetcbcounter}{demo-\thetcbcounter.tex}}}
{Proposition}

\NewTotalTColorBox{\demop}{mm}{% Démonstration d'une proposition
    enhanced,breakable,fonttitle=\bfseries,
    sharp corners,
    title=Démonstration de la proposition~\ref{prop@#1},
    hypertarget=demop@#1,hyperlink=prop@#1
}
{\input{#2}}

\tcbset{no demo/.style={no recording,after upper=}}

\begin{document}

\tcbstartrecording\relax

\chapter{Premier}
    
    \begin{prop}{}{}%with proof
        Premier théorème
        \tcblower
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ligula nisl, laoreet vitae nibh id, dictum finibus est. Sed sed sem ut ligula interdum euismod vel id dolor. Morbi auctor magna nec lectus consectetur rhoncus. Ut sapien mauris, sodales ac tortor at, vestibulum venenatis augue. Nulla fringilla, ante ut feugiat interdum, lectus tellus pulvinar sem, vel gravida nulla odio vitae lacus. Morbi sed quam in sem luctus pharetra. Etiam maximus eleifend nibh, eget bibendum nulla feugiat id. Curabitur eget mauris imperdiet, vulputate lectus in, dapibus mauris. Aliquam sit amet pharetra leo. Nam vehicula vitae nisl a faucibus. Etiam elit odio, finibus facilisis purus at, aliquam luctus purus. Aenean rhoncus, dolor quis lacinia eleifend, ipsum erat commodo quam, eget molestie lacus dolor et felis.
    \end{prop}
    
    \begin{prop}[no demo]{}{}%without proof
        Deuxième théorème mais sans démo
        \tcblower
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ligula nisl, laoreet vitae nibh id, dictum finibus est. Sed sed sem ut ligula interdum euismod vel id dolor. Morbi auctor magna nec lectus consectetur rhoncus. Ut sapien mauris, sodales ac tortor at, vestibulum venenatis augue. Nulla fringilla, ante ut feugiat interdum, lectus tellus pulvinar sem, vel gravida nulla odio vitae lacus. Morbi sed quam in sem luctus pharetra. Etiam maximus eleifend nibh, eget bibendum nulla feugiat id. Curabitur eget mauris imperdiet, vulputate lectus in, dapibus mauris. Aliquam sit amet pharetra leo. Nam vehicula vitae nisl a faucibus. Etiam elit odio, finibus facilisis purus at, aliquam luctus purus. Aenean rhoncus, dolor quis lacinia eleifend, ipsum erat commodo quam, eget molestie lacus dolor et felis.
    \end{prop}
    
    \begin{prop}{}{}%with proof
        Troisième théorème
        \tcblower
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ligula nisl, laoreet vitae nibh id, dictum finibus est. Sed sed sem ut ligula interdum euismod vel id dolor. Morbi auctor magna nec lectus consectetur rhoncus. Ut sapien mauris, sodales ac tortor at, vestibulum venenatis augue. Nulla fringilla, ante ut feugiat interdum, lectus tellus pulvinar sem, vel gravida nulla odio vitae lacus. Morbi sed quam in sem luctus pharetra. Etiam maximus eleifend nibh, eget bibendum nulla feugiat id. Curabitur eget mauris imperdiet, vulputate lectus in, dapibus mauris. Aliquam sit amet pharetra leo. Nam vehicula vitae nisl a faucibus. Etiam elit odio, finibus facilisis purus at, aliquam luctus purus. Aenean rhoncus, dolor quis lacinia eleifend, ipsum erat commodo quam, eget molestie lacus dolor et felis.
    \end{prop}
    
    \begin{prop}{}{}%with proof
        Quatrième théorème
        \tcblower
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ligula nisl, laoreet vitae nibh id, dictum finibus est. Sed sed sem ut ligula interdum euismod vel id dolor. Morbi auctor magna nec lectus consectetur rhoncus. Ut sapien mauris, sodales ac tortor at, vestibulum venenatis augue. Nulla fringilla, ante ut feugiat interdum, lectus tellus pulvinar sem, vel gravida nulla odio vitae lacus. Morbi sed quam in sem luctus pharetra. Etiam maximus eleifend nibh, eget bibendum nulla feugiat id. Curabitur eget mauris imperdiet, vulputate lectus in, dapibus mauris. Aliquam sit amet pharetra leo. Nam vehicula vitae nisl a faucibus. Etiam elit odio, finibus facilisis purus at, aliquam luctus purus. Aenean rhoncus, dolor quis lacinia eleifend, ipsum erat commodo quam, eget molestie lacus dolor et felis.
    \end{prop}
    
    \begin{prop}{}{}%with proof
        Cinquième théorème
        \tcblower
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ligula nisl, laoreet vitae nibh id, dictum finibus est. Sed sed sem ut ligula interdum euismod vel id dolor. Morbi auctor magna nec lectus consectetur rhoncus. Ut sapien mauris, sodales ac tortor at, vestibulum venenatis augue. Nulla fringilla, ante ut feugiat interdum, lectus tellus pulvinar sem, vel gravida nulla odio vitae lacus. Morbi sed quam in sem luctus pharetra. Etiam maximus eleifend nibh, eget bibendum nulla feugiat id. Curabitur eget mauris imperdiet, vulputate lectus in, dapibus mauris. Aliquam sit amet pharetra leo. Nam vehicula vitae nisl a faucibus. Etiam elit odio, finibus facilisis purus at, aliquam luctus purus. Aenean rhoncus, dolor quis lacinia eleifend, ipsum erat commodo quam, eget molestie lacus dolor et felis.
    \end{prop}
    
    \begin{prop}{}{}%with proof
        Sixième théorème
        \tcblower
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ligula nisl, laoreet vitae nibh id, dictum finibus est. Sed sed sem ut ligula interdum euismod vel id dolor. Morbi auctor magna nec lectus consectetur rhoncus. Ut sapien mauris, sodales ac tortor at, vestibulum venenatis augue. Nulla fringilla, ante ut feugiat interdum, lectus tellus pulvinar sem, vel gravida nulla odio vitae lacus. Morbi sed quam in sem luctus pharetra. Etiam maximus eleifend nibh, eget bibendum nulla feugiat id. Curabitur eget mauris imperdiet, vulputate lectus in, dapibus mauris. Aliquam sit amet pharetra leo. Nam vehicula vitae nisl a faucibus. Etiam elit odio, finibus facilisis purus at, aliquam luctus purus. Aenean rhoncus, dolor quis lacinia eleifend, ipsum erat commodo quam, eget molestie lacus dolor et felis.
    \end{prop}


\tcbstoprecording

\cleardoublepage

\tcbinputrecords

\end{document}
```

As you can see in this MWE, I tried with hyperlink and hypertarget, like in the documentation of tcolorbox (page 220).
But the hyperlinks do not work:

- the links theorem->proof always get me to the last page
- the links proof->theorem also always get me to the last page

(In fact, that's worse than without hyperlink/hypertarget. Because if I delete them, the normal behaviour of hyperref gives me the hyperlink  proof->theorem just by clicking on the number of the proof, but in that case, I do not have hyperlink theorem->proof).

And furthermore, where there are no proofs (with the no demo style), of course there musn't be any link. So when there is `\begin[no demo]{prop}{}{}`, there shoudn't be any hyperlink in the theorem. Maybe with a test if no demo, ...

I hope I am clear

Comment: Try to remove `hyperlink=prop@#1` from `\NewTotalTColorBox` definition.

Comment: Thank you@Zarko but it doesn'work. The links from theorems to proofs always get me to the last page and the links from proofs to theorems also always don't do anything

Comment: Hm, in my test of your MWE, where I use up-to-date MiKTeX installation, works as desired. You may try to upgrade your LaTeX installation.

Comment: Hm, as I see, in such  cases links are not presented since  you haven't proof. Or I misunderstood you?

Comment: @Zarko My installation is uptodate (Miktek). And how to suppress the hyperlink where there is no proof? If I delete what you said the link from proofs to theorems work, but only by clicking on the number of the proof. The entire proof should be a hyperlink. When the theorem is simple, there is no need for a proof so in that case there shouldn't be an hyperlink since there is no proof. So if there is \begin[no demo]{prop}, there shoudn't be any hyperlink. And I add that the hyperlink from proof to theorem is the normal behaviour of hyperref. It works without hypertargets, ...

Comment: Well, than please make better explanation in the question (edit it!), what is your problem. I'm not expert for `hyperref`, so can't help you further.

Comment: try with `hypertarget=prop@\thetcbcounter,hyperlink=demop@\thetcbcounter,`. Using `#1` looks fishy.

Comment: Thank you@UlrikeFischer It works perfectly fine. Any idea for when there is no proof?